# Forcing integer constant to be quadword

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Writing a compiler for class, and no one in the class could figure out exactly why we couldn't do the straight-forward thing.

```
cmpq %r13, %r10
movq $0, %r10
cmovne $1, %r10
```

My best guess is that since cmovXX doesn't explicitly define the size of its arguments like movq or movl, $1 doesn't know how big to be, and therefore, throws a type mismatch tantrum.

My question is, how does one force an integer constant to be a quadword? $1q didn't work, so I'm out of guesses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. `cmov` is simply not available (neither Intel, nor AMD created such an encoding of this particular instruction) with an immediate operand. It operates only on registers and memory locations.

Forcing a particular size of an instruction in AT&T syntax is done by appending one of the size prefixes to the instruction's mnemonic - just the way you have done it.

The only instruction in the x86-64 instruction set that can accept a quadword (64-bit) immediate is the `mov` instruction with a 64-bit register. However, doing `movq $0, %rax` will give you the ordinary encoding with a 32-bit immediate. In order to force the assembler to emit a 64-bit immediate, you have to use `movabs $0, %rax`.